# Self signed certificate and SSL in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

For a schoolproject I have a client and a rest-api. Users log into the client using a login form.
When they perform a certain action that makes a call from the client to the API server, the client first sends the username and password through a URL for authentication. The rest-api then sends a JWT token back for the client to use on subsequent calls.

I'm now trying to implement HTTPS to send the username and password for the authentication. I've followed this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate)

However the guide uses resttemplate instead of webclient (which I'm using on the client side to call the rest-api endpoints).

So I've generated a pk12 file per the guide and added it to the rest server along with the following properties:

```
#https config
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/rideService.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=geheim
# The alias mapped to the certificate
server.ssl.key-alias=rideService

security.require-ssl=true
```

This works according to postman.

Now I'm trying to configure the client side but I can't get it to work. I've added the same pk12 file to resources and added the following code to the webclient:

```
@Bean
    public WebClient createSSLWebClient() throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(trustStorePath)), trustStorePass.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, trustStorePass.toCharArray());
        SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                .forClient()
                .keyManager(keyManagerFactory)
                .build();
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext));
        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                .filter(logResponse())     // filterfunctie toevoegen aan de WebClient
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .build();
    }
```

I always get "BAD request". I'm still starting to get my around it all, so I've also tried setting it as a trustmanager, but with the same result...Can anyone enlighten me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually created an SSL certificate for your host? Maybe that's the part you are missing. By a quick look I didnt see the tutorial setting up SSL in the keystore at all.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to this. I thought the PK12 file you place in the resources folder is the SSL certificate?

Comment: No, it is merely a secured container which you use to store your certificates. But keytool has a convenience API that lets you create certificates in that store and it seems the tutorial even uses it:

"keytool -genkeypair -alias baeldung -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore baeldung.jks -validity 3650"

Die you get a prompt where you had to provide, location, department, common name, etc... ?

Comment: Because this usually sets up an SSL key-pair. The important part is, that you provide your services host as the "common name", if you run it locally then it would be localhost.
Or you create some localhost alias in your systems hosts file, and use that as the common name.

Comment: I did get a prompt to provide all the above information. I used the first command to generate the genkeypai pk12 file. So If I regenerate the pk12 file with common name "localhost" it might work?

Comment: As I said, it depends on where you run your service and how you will call it.
If you run it locally, and you call your REST api via e.g. "https://localhost:xxxx/api". , then yes.

Comment: If I could help please accept the answer and upvote =)